# Sort Number: Gold, Silver, Bronze

Tags: php, html

my problem:
I want a working Number sort, thats what I got:

```
$mynumber=7915503;
echo substr($mynumber, 0, 3)." Gold ". substr($mynumber, 3, 2)." Silver " . substr($mynumber, 5, 2)." Bronze ";
```

With that number, it works.
Output: 791 Gold 55 Silver 03 Bronze

But if I change the Number like 9, it will Output: 9 Gold Silver Bronze
I want put the Number 9 in and Output: 0 Gold 0 Silver 9 Bronze

Comment: Just to make sure: The first 3 digits are reserved for gold, then 2 for silver and 2 for bronze?

Comment: I want a Point system on my Homepage and the output of the count changes.
My english is not the best but if I got only 1949 Points, than I want a output:
0 Gold 19 Silver and 49 Bronze.
You understand?

Comment: So, what hinders you from using something like `$x = array('gold'=>55, 'silver'=>8, 'bronze'=>17);`?

Comment: Yes so, the first 3 numbers are for Gold, next 2 for silver and then 2 for bronze.

Comment: Because I only got 1 number...

Comment: Sounds like you're developing this system. Throw in an array instead of a number - why not?

Comment: because I already used the number outfit for other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are most likely more clever solutions....

```
<?php
$data = array(7915503, 9, 11, 211, 2211, 32211,332211, 3332211);

foreach( $data as $x ) {
    echo $x, ' -> ';
    $bronze = substr($x, -2); $x = substr($x, 0, -strlen($bronze));
    $silver = substr($x, -2); $x = substr($x, 0, -strlen($silver));
    $gold = substr($x, -3);

    printf("gold:%d silver:%d bronze:%d\r\n", $gold, $silver, $bronze);
}
```

prints

```
7915503 -> gold:791 silver:55 bronze:3
9 -> gold:0 silver:0 bronze:9
11 -> gold:0 silver:0 bronze:11
211 -> gold:0 silver:2 bronze:11
2211 -> gold:0 silver:22 bronze:11
32211 -> gold:3 silver:22 bronze:11
332211 -> gold:33 silver:22 bronze:11
3332211 -> gold:333 silver:22 bronze:11
```

edit:  doooh, yes there are :

```
foreach( $data as $x ) {
    echo $x, ' -> ';
    $bronze = $x % 100;
    $silver = ($x / 100 ) % 100;
    $gold = ($x / 10000 ) % 1000;

    printf("gold:%d silver:%d bronze:%d\r\n", $gold, $silver, $bronze);
}
```

same output.

Comment: But if I do it like this with that number:
80140571
It will give me "gold:14 silver:5 bronze:71"
And thats wrong, normal its gold: 8014 silver: 5 bronze: 71

Comment: I did it according to "Yes so, the first 3 numbers are for Gold, next 2 for silver and then 2 for bronze" in case gold can have _more than 3 digits_, use `$gold = intval($x / 10000 );`